# Simple Function Mocking in Python

Tags: python, mocking

I'm trying to do what I feel like should be a pretty simple mock in python.

I have a tree that looks like this:

```
- src
  - auth
    - authenticator.py
  - http_client
    - auth_client.py
- tests
  - test_authenticator.py
```

My `authenticator.py` looks like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("src/http_client")

import auth_client

def authenticate_request(headers="", env="dev"):
   # logic...
   auth_client.do_auth(headers)
   # logic...
```

Then `auth_client.py` looks like:

```
import json
import requests

def do_auth(headers):
    url = "https://FAKE_URL.com"
    r = requests.get(url, headers)
    return r.json()
```

And my `test_authenticator.py` has a test that looks like

```
import mock

import sys
sys.path.append("src/auth")
sys.path.append("src/http_client")

import authenticator as auth
import auth_client

    @mock.patch('auth_client.do_auth')
    def test_good(self, mock_request):
        headers = FAKE_HEADERS
        mock_request.return_value = '{\"response:\": 200}'
        body, statusCode = auth.authenticate_request(
            headers=headers)
        self.assertEqual(200, statusCode)
        # self.assertEqual(body, "Token must have kid")


def mock_request():
    return "{\"response\":200}"
```

But I can't seem to actually mock the function. When I run my tests with `pytest` I get in the coverage that it's hitting auth_client even though I don't want it to.

How do I properly mock this function?

Thanks!

Comment: Covering the file makes sense because your importing it. The mock occurs after the real `do_auth` is imported, but it should be getting mocked before being called. This behavior typically isn't an issue.

Comment: You can determine if you mock object is being used by inspecting `mock_request.mock_calls`

Comment: Ahhh! I see now! Sorry -- stupid mistake!